# Do this fact table alteration change the grain?

Tags: dimension, fact

The fact table is a weekly snapshot of help desk tickets with 1 row per ticket per week.  The ticket dimension contains TicketAgeTarget.  I would like to add to the fact table TicketAgeTargetIndicator which is simply 1 or 0 set by the age of the ticket exceeding the TicketAgeTarget, or not.  Now TicketAgeTargetIndicator is cumulative which qualifies as a fact however my feeling is the grain is altered?  Is it?

Answer (score 0):

It's altered if your logic depends on days (or a finer grain) rather than weeks.  Imagine if you had a separate record for all tickets each *day*.  Would they all switch from 0 to 1 on the same day, or would they tick over in batches, one day at a time?  If the latter, then yes your grain has changed.

You may be able to retain your current grain by splitting your facts into "Num Old Tickets" and "Num New Tickets".